# Codeception 2.1 PageObject doesn't work

Tags: codeception

Looks like PageObject doesn't work any more in Codeception 2.1
exactly it is impossible to use methods in PageObject class!

I do not want to put any methods to AcceptancTtester class, I would like to keep it as on example in codeception website in PageObject class

Just simply try to reproduce provided by codeception example from this page http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#PageObjects

When try to run will get an error like:

```
[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Argument 1 passed to Page\Login::__construct() must be an instance of Page\AcceptanceTester
```

I guess it is because of _bootstrap.php is empty now

Could some one tell what we should I add to _bootstrap.php file (Before it profiled automatically while creating new Page using generate command from console)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in documentation:

AcceptanceTester is not in the Page namespace.

Change

`public function __construct(AcceptanceTester $I)`

to

`public function __construct(\AcceptanceTester $I)`

Comment: Great thanks @Naktibalda
Could you also tell me please how to call variables/functions from one PageObject page in other
For example before codeception update I was able to write code like this

Class LoginPage{
RegistrationPage::$emailField;
}

Comment: Have you declared it static?

Comment: Sorry for delay, yes it is static

Comment: actually I have to mention use Page\RegistrationPage as RegistrationPage; in LoginPage
thx for help